# How to use bsondump in windows?

Tags: json, mongodb, bson

How to convert the BSON into JSON from MongoDB.

I inserted documents into MongoDB then I get the following error.

This what I get

```
C:\mongodb\bin>bsondump collection.bson> collection.json error: boost::filesystem::file_size:
```

The system cannot find the `filespecified:"collection.bson"`

Comment: Well, are you sure the file `collection.bson` is in the `mongodb\bin` folder? The error message is pretty clear. Otherwise, your syntax looks correct.

Comment: No first of all i dont know where this bson files are located and who to generate it. My problem is to get json file of the db values inserted in Mongodb. so clear me with this.

Comment: `bsondump` is for dumping BSON, not Json, hence then name. You can export as other formats with another command line tool: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/

Answer (score 0):

please use the absolute directory of collection.bson file or see whether the file is in C:\mongodb\bin or not

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, you have to run the mongodump, which makes the bson file. It creates a dump folder, and it makes for every database an other folder. After that you have to run bsondump coll.bson > coll.json.